# AMD Ryzen 2500U blank screen on boot after update

Tags: boot, amd-ryzen

After doing an update, booting, grub screen shows. Once I entered, I got a totally blank screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: nothing in that link to my solution here

Comment: Same thing happened to me, adding `nomodeset` to the GRUB options helped... but in the meantime, I've upgraded to F21 BIOS.  Between that and the current kernel version, a lot seems worse, backlight control seems to have stopped, and after suspend the screen is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to boot into root terminal and delete this file.

```
sudo rm /lib/firmware/amdgpu_raven_dmcu.bin
```

Worth bumping anyway as the last update restored that file which is causing the problem somehow.

Comment: update: doing a clonezilla backup first, to be safe.

Comment: update: doing a clonezilla backup first, to be safe. I then went here to install the latest kernel https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3-rc1/  downloading 4 of them, not the latency and doing a dpkg -i *.deb - make sure you don't have other deb files there . system complained about unsigned kernel, so I had to disable secure boot in BIOS. I then reinstated the deleted /lib/firmware/amdgpu_raven_dmcu.bin which I had copied to /lib/firmware/amdgpu_raven_dmcu.bin.BAK. and that new kernel now boots ok. also suspend seems to be working,

Comment: but I still need to unplug usb mouse and keyboard else they still get lost on resume. early days yet as suspend is semi random so far this year with other kernels.  and F1 2017 from Steam  locked up after complaining about incompatible drivers, though I can work on it. hopefully I can get it to run with better graphics.

Comment: I had to revert back as new graphics problems were too much, lines all over the place, mispositioned windows etc. note that it was not the apt update on the latest official kernel that allowed for the raven file to be in place, it was this latest buggy 5.3r1 kernel. suspend also went well at first but then not at all, or lost USB, or even the laptop keyboard.

Comment: interesting comments here.   https://community.amd.com/thread/238156

Comment: fairly big upgrade today for 19.10 apparmor gir1.2-pango-1.0 gnome-shell gnome-shell-common libapparmor1 libnvidia-cfg1-430 libnvidia-common-430 libnvidia-compute-430........................ kernel from  5.00.23.21 to  5.00.23.24

Comment: ok, so the latest update has a lot of amd 430 graphics in it which looked promising... it also, again, changes the grub.cfg timeouts to zero (I got caught out this time, but I had done a Clonezilla backup ... I was logged in to ubuntu but with the blank screen, because I had unwisely reinstated that raven file.) . rebooting now without it to see, and should get a grub menu by resetting the timeouts=0 to =10 in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file

Comment: alas, I still need to delete the raven_dmcu.bin file to get anything other than a black screen.  and slightly off topic, perhaps because of the recent F21 BIOS update for my HP Envy 360 , I cannot USB boot onto Ubuntu or Mint, or Ubuntu CD fortunately Clonezilla still boots. I turned on or off secure boot. mmmm! grhhhhhhh!

Comment: yep , I need to enable legacy in BIOS to boot to Ubuntu (but not Clonezilla, go figure)

Comment: ok, I have now (touch wood) installed kernel 5.3.0-050300rc2-generic
and it boots ok with the amdgpu_raven_dmcu.bin file intact. as that manual kernel is unsigned, BIOS is secure boot disabled for now.