# Ubuntu 19.04 - blank screen after boot

Tags: boot, encryption, 19.04

My computer is a Dell XPS laptop.

I was able to us my Ubuntu 19.04 installation without any problems, but today while working it started to act strange. Every command I would enter into the terminal resulted in `permission denied`. So I decided to reboot.

I would then enter the password to decrypt the partion, and then it would go to a blank screen, sometimes with a static `_` in the upper left corner.

#### Things I tried

- Changed `/etc/default/grub` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`
- Tried purging nvidia, but nothing was removed, presumably because it wasn't installed.
- So I tried to install the Nvidia graphics driver with `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390`. This slightly changed the result, but only slightly. Now the screen is almost blank, with the exception of a green OK in the corner. However, on subsequent reboots I now no longer get the green OK. I just get a static `_`.

  Output from `hwinfo --gfxcard --short`:

  ```
  nvidia GP107M [Geforce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]  
  Intel UHD Graphics 630 Mobile
  ```
- I tried `sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.mybak` but get `/etc/X11/xorg.conf no such file or directory`.
- Tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`. And this uninstalled a lot of stuff!
- Tried `sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` but this `E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
- Tried `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` but this `E: Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`
- Tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg` - but nothing happened.
- Tried `sudo chmod a-x /usr/bin/compiz` and get `cannot access /usr/bin/compiz: No such file or directory`. From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen#Analysis_Techniques
- Tried `sudo rm /lib/firmware/amdgpu_raven_dmcu.bin` but got `No such file or directory`
- Tried `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current` but got `E: Package nvidia-current has no installation candidate`
- Tried: 
  `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and then `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)`. Then reboot, but still the same issue remains. From https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1744248&p=10744546#post10744546
- Tried setting `acpi=off` in grub. This results in the boot sequence hanging at `Freeing unused kernel image memory 2576k`. I also tried `pci=noacpi`. This didnt change the result. I also tried setting `acpi=strict`. This also didnt change the result. From https://askubuntu.com/a/962099/17643
- Tried setting `apm=off`. This didnt change the result. From https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/hang-after-freeing-unused-kernel-memory-211275/#post1384593
- Tried each of the following, individually: `nolapic`, `noapic`, `acpi_osi=“Linux”`, `acpi=ht`, `acpi=noirq` and `pnpacpi=off`.  These didnt change the result, except for the last one which resulted in a stream of errors. From https://askubuntu.com/a/406419/17643
- Tried to recover files using a live cd, and using `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private` but the live cd doesnt have `ecryptfs-recover-private` - instead I get `command not found`. Does anyone know where I can get a Live CD that has `ecryptfs-recover-private` or where I can install this utility from?

Comment: I tried this, but I dont have that file. So, no its not a duplicate.

Comment: my apoligies, you had already said youd tried it. shall I delete my comment here?

Comment: note that  the file to delete was in an amdgpu  subfolder. /lib/firmware/amdgpu/raven_dmcu.bin    and see my latest success with newer kernel and with that file intact, no blank screen.     https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156481/amd-ryzen-2500u-blank-screen-on-boot-after-update/1156482#1156482

Comment: but it did not turn out well, see previous link for update.