# No solution for black screen after nvidia driver update

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I updated the nvidia driver from a 380 version to a 430 using the drivers available in the settings. After restarting the computer it gets stuck in a black screen.

The problem is that I cannot even get access to the terminal. Using recovery mode and trying root console doesn't work since I don't have the root password, but only the password of a user with admin privileges. Nouveau did not work, as replacing "quiet splash" to "nomodeset". Pressing ctrl + alt + f* also presented no success. I also tried replacing "quiet splash" for "text", but no luck.

Any ideas of how to proceed?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this solution: https://askubuntu.com/a/763302/978216

Comment: Pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1 does not work

Comment: If you can cannot get terminal access you can boot the system with a live USB to fix it.

Comment: my solution with default drivers is here... and see latest comment from me regarding the latest kernel. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156481/amd-ryzen-2500u-blank-screen-on-boot-after-update/1156482#comment1937798_1156482