# Can I boot HP Ryzen 2500u BIOS F21 without nomodeset?

Tags: gpu

I upgraded my HP x360 Ryzen 2500U to BIOS F21.. but seem to need nomodeset to boot Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit.

Without `nomodeset`, it gets so stuck on a black screen and the keyboard doesn't work (no capslock etc) so havr to hard reset.

Not quite sure how to get this working again.

Under F19, and kernel 4.19(ish), it was working fairly well..  at some point I had to start using the recovery console to boot though as booting would just get stuck.

After upgrading to F21 I found `nomodeset` would allow booting, but the brightness controls don't work any more.

The touchscreen seems to have stopped working under Linux too.

Comment: Do you have Nvidia video hardware?  Have you installed the Nvidia proprietary drivers yet?

Comment: No, it is AMD Vega 8.

Comment: possible dupe of 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156481/amd-ryzen-2500u-blank-screen-on-boot-after-update